# Can´t access the default switchboard sound settings

Tags: wingpanel, sound, indicator-sound

Basically, I’m unable to use switchboard-plug-sound despite showing up in the switchboard, despite being installed, despite still working and having it's indicators. Once I click on it from the settings, It instant close itself.
Due to that, I’m currently using the pulseaudio audio mixer, but it's pretty bad for me to use it instead of the default Elementary OS one. Anyway to fix that?

I suppose it's mostly due to some packages issues, but i’ve tried to reinstall it and its dependencies.
I also suspect being caused by some modifications done to the tray packages to allow for the usage of indicators once again, but i’ve didn’t have any issues since now with it.

---

I want to clarify, despite it close instantly, You can actually distinguish the menu actually loading, proving it isn’t just missing on the switchboard menu.

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading the switchboard sound application from github. Follow directions in readme file. All dependencies are required.

Comment: It still closes itself despite having the correct dependencies and having no issues or errors when building it from source.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has since been fixed. It was due to the gnome-alsamixer being installed.
Removing it simply fixed this issue/